# How can I call rollback after oracle command is executed?

Tags: c#, winforms, oracle

I have a rollback button and I like to use it, but My rollback button doesnt work some how... How can I effectively use Rollback; ?

```
string myCommand ="Insert into....";
Conn.Open();
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(myCommand, Conn);
cmd.ExecuteScalar();

private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rollback;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to define a transaction object, there you can commit and rollback. Should be like this:

```
OracleTransaction tx;

string myCommand ="Insert into....";
Conn.Open();
tx = Conn.BeginTransaction();
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(myCommand, Conn);
cmd.ExecuteScalar();

private void Commit_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tx.Commit();
}

private void Rollback_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tx.Rollback();
}
```

Comment: And you are going to keep a SQL connection/transaction open until a user presses a button.  Lots of potential for dead locks.

Comment: Working with transactions is quite standard in RDBMS. Having a **dead** lock in this situation is almost impossible, in worst case another user has to wait until the first user ends his transaction, i.e. a lock. The code ist just an example how to invoke COMMIT and ROLLBACK. Usually you put the ROLLBACK inside an exception handler.

Answer (score -3):

For the "Insert into ...." just execute a "Delete ...." for the rollback.

A better pattern is to keep a list of Commands.  Each Command has a DoSql and UndoSql property. This allows rollback (UndoSql) and redo (DoSql).

More info at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compensating_transaction.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but myCommand is not static. This is just an example. Inside myCommand I will have difeerent DML command. therefore  Better to make a dynamic.

Comment: -1 for suggesting that a "delete" is equivalent to a rollback

Comment: Jeffrey if you look at his code.  Its not a SQL rollback because the Insert has been committed.  So to perform an UNDO the OP must DELETE.

Comment: @user...This is why I suggested you use a Command pattern.  So that the DML command (do and undo) can be associated.

Comment: I have enough reputation to suffer a few -1's.  But please consider my comment to @Wernfried.

Comment: Indeed, in some rare cases it makes sense to prepare/execute two commands, one for INSERT and one for DELETE in this case. However, the question is clearly "How to make a **ROLLBACK**?" and a ROLLBACK is certainly different than a DELETE (after an INSERT)

Comment: Transaction will be best option.